# Using a variable in ng-class AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have 3 divs which will have a class "yellow" assigned according to a specific value using the following `ng-class="{item.color : item.value}`

This class yellow is also stored in a variable which is item.color

However I want to insert the class name through a variable by using `ng-class="{item.color : item.value}` but it's not working because item.color is not a valid expression. But if I use `ng-class="item.color"` (which gives me a different result I don't want) it works just fine.

You have more information in the following plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/unZDIWc6DvM4cLpALKSK?p=preview

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will highlight the div yellow if value is `true` if this is what you intend.

```
 ng-class="item.value && item.color"
```

OR

```
 ng-class="item.value ? item.color : ''"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Both of them work. :)